Is the idea of a rigid body compatible with Newtonian mechanics?
It is known that rigid bodies cannot exist in the framework of special relativity by causality arguments. But recently I saw a video on YouTube that claims rigid bodies are not compatible with Newtonian mechanics, namely the strong third law (PSE discussion here).$^\dagger$ The law basically states

For every force (action), there's a collinear reaction force of equal magnitude, pointing in the opposite direction.

The video references this paper$^\ddagger$, which analyses the following two-body model and notes that the tangential force $F$ causing rotation contradicts the storng third law, assuming rigidity, since the reaction must not be collinear with action. Then the author goes through a calculation assuming non-rigidity, deriving the correct result, and concludes that

...rigid bodies are inconsistent with classical (non-relativistic) physics... The rigid-body model employed here violates the strong third law and angular momentum conservation (via Noether’s theorem), leading to a completely incorrect
statement of the rotational second law.


However, opinions seem divided on the paper (i.e. this and the comments therein). My question is, is it true that the idea of rigid body is incompatible not just with relativity, but with Newtonian mechanics? If not, is there a problem with the formulation/application of the strong form of Newton's third law here?

$^\dagger$ I have left a comment under the video asking for clarification on the details of the "strong form", but my guess is that it is a statement about angular momentum conservation instead of linear momentum conservation.
$^\ddagger$ Cross, D. J. (2014). The physical origin of torque and of the rotational second law

Do you have a problem with John Rennie’s answer in the link?

I don't like these pedantic terms (strong/weak form) either. I think what John Rennie's answer says is that the "weak form" (momentum conservation) holds no matter what, but does not discuss angular momentum conservation. What the paper refers to as the "strong form" talks about angular momentum conservation, and claims that rigidity contradicts it.

Please state the problem completely iso that your question is self contained. As it is now I have to study a video and a paper to know what it is about. I avoid this effort also because I don't believe there is one.

@JonathanHuang The section you quote from the paper is incorrect and fails to account for all the internal forces in the rod, in particular the internal bending moments in the rod. They are present in addition to the shear force $T$.


My question is, is it true that the idea of rigid body is incompatible not just with relativity, but with Newtonian mechanics ?

The concept of a perfectly rigid body requires infinitely stiff materials, so it is easy to see that it is not physically realistic. However, as an idealisation it is a useful first approximation in many scenarios - just as Newtonian mechanics is a useful first approximation to relativity, and relativity itself is a useful first approximation to an as yet unknown theory of quantum gravity.

I'm sorry, but I don't think this answers my question at all. I'm more concerned with whether the arguments used in the paper/video are valid, and whether rigid bodies are compatible theoretically with Newtonian formulation.

@JonathanHuang I agree. This has nothing to do with the actual question asked.

@JonathanHuang I quoted the question that you asked. If you were expecting a review of the paper's method (rather than just its conclusions) then you should make that clearer - although your question would then be likely closed as being off topic.

@JonathanHuang You asked if a rigid body is incompatible with Newtonian mechanics. I believe gandalf61 has answered that.
